# Java 8 Annotations on Instance creation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8

In the Javadocs for Annotations, it states that the following can be written in Java 8:

```
new @Interned MyObject();
```

Is there anyway to retrieve the annotation @Interned from an object annotated like this via reflection? I'm familiar with the typical ways of retrieving annotations from methods, fields, classes, etc, but I'd like to know if it's possible to associate a particular instance with an annotation at runtime in Java 8.

Comment: Have you tried using the _"typical ways of retrieving annotations from methods, fields, classes, etc"_?  Have you experimented at all?

Comment: [The retention of @Interned is specified](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/interning/qual/Interned.html) as `RUNTIME`, but I haven't tried it.  These new annotations are designed for the new [Checker Framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html).  There may not be a good way to retrieve these new annotations without access to the source code or the raw bytes of the class files.

Comment: @markspace and their example in 4.2.1 is: `@Interned Double internedDoubleZero = new @Interned Double(0);` so the annotation is  on the field *as well as* on the new instance... So if you use it only on the right hand side it is probably only available at compile time.

Comment: Right, that and a few other things make me nervous about recommending the OP access these annotations.  The Checker Framework is a tool you should use mostly as-is.  The idea is not for a coder to roll their own checker framework at run time.  That sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I didn't know it was made specifically for the Checker Framework, but I have used Checker Framework. I was wondering if anyone knew whether there was a method somewhere that allowed you to get annotations off object instances, because the methods I know, such as the `.getClass().getAnnotations()` idea are specifically for classes, fields, parameters, and methods, and specifcally not for instances. Also, the RUNTIME retention, as far as I know, is so that any annotation in general can be accessed at runtime, otherwise you can't even get it off of a method, field, class, or parameter at runtime.

Comment: These annotations are meant for the compiler. http://www.infoq.com/articles/Type-Annotations-in-Java-8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An annotation applied to an instance creation like `new @Anno Object()` is *not* a property of the created object but only of the (compile-time) type of the `new` expression. At runtime the actual type of the object does not have the annotation just like it has no Generic type parameters you might have specified at the instance creation.

Just consider the following example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@interface Anno { int value(); }
```

…

```
@Anno(1) Object o=new @Anno(2) Object();
@Anno(3) Object p=(@Anno(4) Object)o;
```

Here, the simple object goes through several type changes, from `@Anno(2) Object` to `@Anno(1) Object` to `@Anno(4) Object` to `@Anno(3) Object` and at the end of this code the same object is even held by two differently typed variables, `@Anno(1) Object` and `@Anno(3) Object`, at the same time!

You may use audit tools to verify whether these type transitions are legal in respect to whatever semantics `@Anno` implies, but to the Java language itself they have no meaning and will be always accepted. And at runtime, the type of the instance will always be `Object` not being affected by the type annotation.

The Reflection API provides ways to query the annotated types of declarations of classes and members which includes parameter and return types of methods but you cannot query the type annotations of a `new` expression as you will not be able to find out whether a method actually contains a `new` expression, let alone type annotations applied to that `new` expression.

There might be 3rd party libraries settling on byte code processing libraries which will provide access to these annotations at runtime…

Comment: The design center for type annotations is enabling better static analysis of programs.  These annotations are available reflectively for the portions of the Java program that reflection covers -- class and member declarations.  But reflection does not drill down to the level of Java expressions -- and quite likely never well.  And, even if they did, this still wouldn't help (think about how you might implement this, and the costs it would impose.)